# Can i import org.chromium.content.* to MainActivity.java in application level?

Tags: android, import, android-4.4-kitkat, android-source

Can i import org.chromium.content.* to MainActivity.java in application level? I have the AOSP environment and compile in linux server. I would like to call the Class from that package. Is it possible and guide me the way to implement it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After did some reading and research, as per [design document](https://www.chromium.org/developers/content-module), my question is not possible to implement.